# selecting preceding cousins (including siblings)

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, xpath-2.0, xpath-3.1

I often have the problem of wanting to select the previous 'cousin' to a node.

For example:

```
<root>
    <level1>
        <level2 id="1"/>  
        <level2 id="2"/>  
        <level2 id="3"/>  
        <level2 id="4"/>  
    </level1>
    <level1>
        <level2 id="5">
            <level2 id="9"/>
        </level2>  
        <level2 id="6"/>  
        <level2 id="7"/>  
        <level2 id="8"/>  
    </level1>
</root>
```

If the context node is

```
/root/level1/level2[@id='6']
```

I don't want `"id=9"`; I want `"id=5"`.

Similarly if the context node is

```
/root/level1/level2[@id='5']
```

I want `"id=4"`.

So....`preceding-sibling` does work in the former case but not the latter.  `preceding` selects in the latter case but not the former.
(And there are probably a multitude of other cases.)

So my current solution is this (using `id=6` as the context node...I could put it in a function, but this should be clear enough)

```
(/root/level1/level2[@id='6']/preceding::level2 intersect /root/level1/level2)[last()]
```

this *does* work, but seems..convoluted, and possibly inefficient...am I missing a simpler solution?

(I'm current using XPath 3.1 in XSLT 3, but I think its a general question.)

(I've limited this to XPath 2.0+, but I'll probably open up the question to XPath 1.0, as that seems even worse because `intersect` doesn't exist...but I'll do that in another post.)

For XSLT 1.0 this works:

```
/root/level1/level2[@id='6']/preceding::level2[parent::level1[parent::root]][1]
```

and is debatably a better solution.

What I'd like to do is

```
/root/level1/level2[@id='6']/preceding::(root/level/level2)[1]
```

and have that be interpreted as a match on the path `root/level/level2`,
but I don't think that's valid?

---

there are some really good answer here, I want completely clear what the question was, apologies.

I'm looking for all 'nth cousins' where 0th cousins are siblings.

irritatingly the elegant solutions just get 0th and 1st, and the more complex solutions are 'correct' but quite clunky (no offense).

For the moment the most elegant solutions I have is to (as a programmer) take the absolute simple path to your current node, in this case

```
let $this = ....

(root/level1/level2)[. << $this][last()]
```

the clever solutions do this programatically (one using depth, the other the path), and are a bit mind boggling to me.

the elegant solutions, use the '<<' operator, but only match 0th and 1st siblings (which was a reasonable interpretation).

the XSLT 1.0 solution similarly only does 0th and 1st, and I think I'd actually use the `parent::` solution above, and match the full path to the root to ensure all cousins are matched.

(this of course presumes you know the full path, though martin honnens solution works in general).

Comment: I am not sure there is a simple solution. And are you looking for any `level2` "cousin" or only for those having the same ancestor structure (as in your example you test for `root/level1/level2`)?

Comment: thats what i do in the interest "intersect /root/level1/level2"

Comment: Yes, I see that, I just wonder if there were a `<root><foo><level2/></foo><level1><level2/></level1></root>`, if you considered or if you wouldn't consider the `level2` inside the `foo` element a cousin of the `level2` inside of the `level1` element?

Comment: (in this context) cousins are their position in the hierachy, not their name, maybe the example isnt great....what ive done works...but seems quite convoluted to do something seemingly straight forward. The other issue is intersect doesnt work in xpath 1.0...maybe thats a different question

Comment: Your new requirements (*I'm looking for all 'nth cousins' where 0th cousins are siblings*) are unclear and appear to contradict your original requirements (*select the previous 'cousin' to a node*).  While your first statement of your requirements was supported by your example, it appears that your example now is out-of-date or otherwise inadequate to cover what should and what should not be selected in general.

Comment: hmmm....I'm not sure....the example actually shows i want siblings and 1st cousins, I don't mention nth cousins, that was vague, but I dont see a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, XPath 1.0 is all you need.

Given your input XML, [this](https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet+xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A++version%3D%222.0%22%3E%0D%0A++%3Cxsl%3Aoutput+indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++%3Cxsl%3Atemplate+match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cresults%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Cxsl%3Afor-each+select%3D%22%2F%2Flevel2%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3Ccase+num%3D%22%7B%40id%7D%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3Cxsl%3Avariable+name%3D%22depth%22+select%3D%22count%28ancestor%3A%3A*%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3Cxsl%3Asequence+select%3D%22preceding%3A%3Alevel2%5Bcount%28ancestor%3A%3A*%29+%3D+%24depth%5D%5B1%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3C%2Fcase%3E%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2Fresults%3E%0D%0A++%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Croot%3E%0A++++%3Clevel1%3E%0A++++++++%3Clevel2+id%3D%221%22%2F%3E++%0A++++++++%3Clevel2+id%3D%222%22%2F%3E++%0A++++++++%3Clevel2+id%3D%223%22%2F%3E++%0A++++++++%3Clevel2+id%3D%224%22%2F%3E++%0A++++%3C%2Flevel1%3E%0A++++%3Clevel1%3E%0A++++++++%3Clevel2+id%3D%225%22%3E%0A++++++++++++%3Clevel2+id%3D%229%22%2F%3E%0A++++++++%3C%2Flevel2%3E++%0A++++++++%3Clevel2+id%3D%226%22%2F%3E++%0A++++++++%3Clevel2+id%3D%227%22%2F%3E++%0A++++++++%3Clevel2+id%3D%228%22%2F%3E++%0A++++%3C%2Flevel1%3E%0A%3C%2Froot%3E&input-type=XML) XSLT 2.0 (for the test program – the key XPath is 1.0),

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <results>
      <xsl:for-each select="//level2">
        <case id="{@id}">
          <xsl:variable name="depth" select="count(ancestor::*)"/>
          <xsl:sequence select="preceding::level2[count(ancestor::*) = $depth][1]"/>
        </case>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces these test results,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
   <case num="1"/>
   <case num="2">
      <level2 id="1"/>
   </case>
   <case num="3">
      <level2 id="2"/>
   </case>
   <case num="4">
      <level2 id="3"/>
   </case>
   <case num="5">
      <level2 id="4"/>
   </case>
   <case num="9"/>
   <case num="6">
      <level2 id="5">
         <level2 id="9"/>
      </level2>
   </case>
   <case num="7">
      <level2 id="6"/>
   </case>
   <case num="8">
      <level2 id="7"/>
   </case>
</results>
```

which covers the two cases of concern and produces reasonable results for all starting `level2` elements as well.

Comment: nice, its technically correct, though using depth rather than a path, is a bit scary.

Comment: I believe using depth explicitly makes your particular ***cousin*** requirement clear, but see Michael Kay's [clever way of representing the relationship without an explicit depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78028626/290085).  I really like his solution for its elegance.

Comment: actually I'm relooking at this solution

Comment: I've changed my mind, I think this DOES fulfil the spirit of the question, if I need to apply additional predicates, I think that is a seperate issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an easy expression, I wonder whether the following code using `path` and `xsl:evaluate` implements the requirement:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:cousins" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="path" select="path($node)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="path-without-predicates" select="replace($path, '\[[0-9]+\]', '')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="cousins" as="node()*">
      <xsl:evaluate context-item="$node" xpath="$path-without-predicates"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="$cousins except $node"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:function name="mf:preceding-cousins" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:cousins($node)[. &lt;&lt; $node]"/>
  </xsl:function>
  
  <xsl:template match="level2[@id = 6] | level2[@id = 5]">
    <xsl:comment>preceding cousin: {mf:preceding-cousins(.)[last()]=>serialize(map{ 'method' : 'xml' })}</xsl:comment>
    <xsl:next-match/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It looks a bit like a "hack" to use the `path` function, then string replacement and `xsl:evaluate` but I don't see a simple, direct XPath.

Comment: ew.....nasty...no offense.....clever....but its the sort of thing you put in a library and hope is correct.

Comment: i'll mark it as the answer if we cant wangle out something better...the <xsl:otherwise> option

Comment: Wait for others like Michael Kay to give their opinions/suggestions on how to approach it.

Comment: youve won by default!...this is the correct interpretation of the problem and is a general solution, Michael Kays answers were alluringly elegant but not nth cousins, and the depth based solution, whilst correct, doesnt give the granulaity of matching the path.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would probably do

```
let $this := .
let $precedingCousins := (../../*/*)[. << $this]
return $precedingCousins[last()]
```

or its equivalent in XSLT.

Comment: eeek...what does "<<" mean? (i'll look it up)

Comment: I assume it means everything preceding in document order

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd, yes see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-node-comparisons "A comparison with the << operator returns true if the left operand node precedes the right operand node in document order; otherwise it returns false.". I did also use that in my code (in XSLT you use `&lt;&lt;`).

Comment: my only issue is it doesnt work in xslt 1.0, but given that I explicitly excluded that, it would seem a bit mean spirited not to mark this as the answer...the key is '<<' which i never knew about...(to me thats function composition ;-))

Comment: @MartinHonnen
to be honest your solution hurt my head so much i didnt comprehend its nuances

Comment: ah sorry...this is also "wrong" in the sense i meant nth cousins....sorry if the question isnt clear

Comment: the use of the << operator though i think means in practice I can do this

Answer (score 1):

An XPath 1.0 solution would be

```
(preceding-sibling::* | ../preceding-sibling::*/*)[last()]
```

Comment: i would mark this as the answer, but, 'cousins' was just an example use case and i find this in general as mind boggling as my 'parent::foo[parent::bar]' variation....actually i think i find it more mind boggling.

Comment: ah though, my parent thing isnt really doing cousins, its doing matching paths segments

Comment: I think it should be [1] not [last()]?...but im splitting hairs

Comment: actually i think this is wrong (though my quesion isnt clear)...this is doing siblings and 1st cousins...I meant nth cousins where 0th cousins are siblings

Comment: It should be `[last()]` not `[1]` because the result of a union expression is in document order.

Comment: ah ok, of course

Answer (score 1):

To do Nth cousins, where N is a parameter supplied dynamically, I would write a recursive function, which necessarily makes it XPath 2.0+.

In XQuery notation

```
declare function my:cousins($node as node(), 
                            $degree as xs:integer) as node()* {
   if ($degree eq 0) 
   then $node/../*
   else my:cousins($node/.., $degree - 1)/*
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tbh, Michael Kay's answer is basically there except it tests the level directly, I'd want a variation on that, that ignored the level and just returned all cousins.

```
<xsl:function name="kooks:cousins" as="node()*">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="$node/../*"/>         
    <xsl:if test="$node/..">
        <xsl:sequence select="kooks:cousins($node/..)/*"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:function>
```

note, like another answer, there is no matching predicate, this just matches all element cousins, and also doesnt handle the previous/next, but this can be done with '<<'

If you know the full path then

```
(/foo/bar/wibble)[. << $this]
```

is simple and comprehendable

where $this is a member of "/foo/bar/wibble"

this MAY work in xslt 1.0, I've not used it, and the order worries me because of the use of node-set (for following you may need to change the order of the union operarands), and as per M Kay's answer the order is document order.

```
<xsl:template mode="preceding-cousin" match="/"/>

<xsl:template mode="preceding-cousin" match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="precedingUnclesRTF">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="preceding-cousin" select=".."/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="precedingUncles" select="msxsl:node-set($precedingUnclesRTF)/*"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$precedingUncles/* | preceding-sibling::*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and the depth answer also works in XSLT 1.0 is simpler than the above, and wont suffer from an exponential copying of nodes as the above does, but does process all the previous nodes in the document, it works in all versions of XSLT and isnt recursive (so wont kill the stack), though i think the recursive function answer can be rewritten as a fold or xsl iteration.

```
<xsl:template mode="preceding-cousin2" match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="depth" select="count(ancestor::*)"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="preceding::*[count(ancestor::*) = $depth]"/>
</xsl:template>
```